# Keep getting NotRegistered - Node gcm

Tags: android, node.js, google-cloud-messaging

So I have a node server that is sending a gcm message. Whenever I uninstall the app and reinstall the app (its in development so Im doing that a lot for testing), I get a result

```
[{ error: 'NotRegistered' }]
```

I cannot figure out why I get that. It will go from working perfectly fine and then to throwing that error when I try to test a newer version. I have all the keys setup properly: gcm enabled, server api key, and project id.

Like I said, it does work sometimes. But when I uninstall the app, i get a not registered error.

Comment: Whether or not your boss kills you is not really relevant to the question, keep it clean ;-)

Comment: Are you aware that a GCM registration id is not device unique, and not even app unique, and renewed any time you remove/reinstall the app?

Comment: I am using phonegap-plugin-push to get the device ID. Whenever I install the app it gets a deviceID with that plugin and sends it to the server which will store it for gcm. So what am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: It is not a device id, it is a GCM registration id, which -as I said- is renewed when you reinstall the app